# creating excel with Greek characters

Tags: php, html, excel, character-encoding

i have used the following headers in order to create xls files that contains Greek characters on the fly.

**first attempt**:

```
header("Content-Type: application/$file_type;charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.$file_ending");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

**second attempt**:

```
header("Content-Type: application/$file_type;charset=windows-1253");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.$file_ending");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

the created file althought it contains the correct Greek characters (viewed with a text editor) when i open it at the ms-excel the Greek characters are shown as sympols.

i have also tried a library that creates xls (open xls binary format) with the same outcome. This library has options to set the codepage and the charset but still nothing.

any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a library then it should have a function to set the encoding to UTF-8. For example, with PEAR's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer (http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected), you would do:

```
<?php
    $workSheet = & $workBook -> addWorksheet('Students');
    $workSheet -> setInputEncoding('utf-8');
?>
```

Of course, you must also make sure that your data are actually utf-8 and not ISO-8859-7 or windows-1253 for example. 
Be aware that this does not support workbook name changing (ie using 'Μαθητές' instead of 'Students')

Comment: thanks @periklis, i have used a different library and worked. i am always using utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about XLS files but if you'd rather use Excel readable CSV files, use UTF-16 encoding (with BOM) and tabs as separators

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

echo chr(255) . chr(254); // Add UTF-16 little-endian BOM

echo mb_convert_encoding("α\tβ\tγ"), 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); // from UTF-8 to UTF-16
```